# not able to push file more than 100mb to git hub

Tags: git, github, limit

I am getting this error when I do so
exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
Is there any way that I can push files more than 100 mb to git hub 
I am trying to push a zip file which is 114 mb .
Is there any simple work around for this.
thank you

Comment: Perhaps if you give them more money than you do today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally no as this is an intentional limitation in GitHub. The reason for this limitation is that git (general git, not GitHub) stores every version of each file. Therefore having multiple revisions of large files will make the repository bloat and increases the clone and fetch times for other users of a repository (see [GitHub Help - Working with large files](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/)).

The way GitHub recommends working with large files is using Git LFS (Large File Storage), generally explained as:

> ... an open-source extension to Git that allows you to work with large
>   files the same way as any other text
>
> With Git Large File Storage, you and your repository's contributors
>   can clone large files from the Git command line, open pull requests,
>   and comment on the diffs. It's the ideal solution for pushing files to
>   GitHub that are larger than 100 MB.

(see GitHub documentation - [versioning large files](https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/)).

As a general recommendation (not necessarily related to GitHub) the best practice would be not to work with big files, and consider other alternatives to your specific case.

Comment: while zipping the file , I am now configuring it to zip the file into two parts. 7-zip provides option to keep max size limit for each part. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100MB. For more details check this link: [GIT - working with large files](https://icl.googleusercontent.com/https://icl.googleusercontent.com/?lite_url=https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/&ei=f9qLPvou&lc=en-IN&s=1)

You can split up your zip file into 2 files of sizes less than 100MB and push the same.

Comment: It seems the link is now broken