# How to push large size file to github?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

I am trying to push **ExpressPlay.framewrok** which is of size 466.00 MB.
But GitHub not allowing to push such large files its limit is 100 MB.

I have tried to use **git lfs install** command in my repository to support large files. But its not working.

does someone know solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: once after installing git lfs you will have to update .gitattributes files by using git lfs track (either file extension/absolute path of file from root directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not able to push file more than 100mb to git hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586977/not-able-to-push-file-more-than-100mb-to-git-hub)

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem while uploading a 4 gb repository.
I wrote this bat script to push files by type. This made
push a lot faster.

## For Linux

```sh
git add **/*.$1
git commit -m "$1"
git push
```

## For Windows

```
set ext=%1
git add **/*.%ext%
git commit -m "%ext%"
git push
```

To upload all `.js` files I'd use

```
>>> this.bat js
```