# Removing git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

How do you do a full remove/unistall of git-lfs please? I did `git lfs uninstall` which returned the following two lines:

```
Hooks for this repository have been removed
Global Git LFS configuration has been removed
```

but the `lfs` folder is still under `.git` and when I do `git status` files come and go in that folder (`.git/lfs/tmp`). It looks to me that `git-lfs` has not probably been removed.
The executable has also been uninstalled from the `uninstall or change a program` window under `control panel` in my windows10 machine.

Comment: when you run git lfs uninstall, it means your new files would not be tracked and pushed to remote lfs server. .git/lfs/tmp is a locall temporary folder to cache lfs files and you should do git lfs prune to clean it up, or just don't need to care about it at all if you don't care about your space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [git-lfs/git-lfs issue 959](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/959), you can delete that folder now.

Before un-installing lfs, a [`git lfs prune`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn) would have help keep that content to a reasonnable size. But now, the folder is no longer needed.

---

As [RYO ENG Lian Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3806250/ryo-eng-lian-hu) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769821/removing-git-lfs/52772489?noredirect=1#comment114799187_52772489), ans explained in "[not able to push file more than 100mb to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29587067/6309)"

> You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100MB.
> For more details check this link: [GIT - working with large files](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files)
>
> You can split up your zip file into 2 files of sizes less than 100MB and push the same.

Comment: tried to `git lfs prune` but still unable connect local repo to github repo

Comment: @RYOENGLianHu OK: could you ask a separate question with your specific details, fir me or others to have a look?

Comment: solved! https://github.com/englianhu/binary.com-interview-question/issues/2

Comment: @RYOENGLianHu Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was that I installed git-lfs on my computer running Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu). When I upgraded the computer to 23.04 (Lunar Lobster), `apt update` at the command prompt started complaining bitterly that the git-lfs repository didn't have a release for Lunar Lobster: and the Software Updater application broke completely, complaining that I had no network connection (??)

I couldn't find the git-lfs repository in the Software and Updates application. In then end I had to list the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory and delete the `git_git-lfs.list` file. After than everything on my computer worked correctly again.