# "GitLab: LFS objects are missing" - How do I delete every trace of LFS in my repository?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm migrating a repository from one origin to another. After updating my remote urls, and running `git push`, I get the error "GitLab: LFS objects are missing."

I would like to delete any trace of LFS in my repository.

I've tried:

[Removing git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769821/removing-git-lfs?rq=3)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699726/472966

I've tried `git lfs uninstall` and deleting the `.git/lfs` directory.

No matter what, every time I push, I get an LFS error. How can I wipe out every trace of `git lfs` from my repository (including in all history).

Comment: There is no simple way. See https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3026 for some very good discussion. But there is no command that migrates a Git LFS repo cleanly and magically to a normal Git repo.

Comment: Both the commands you tried are pretty much pointless. `git lfs uninstall` has no effect on your repo, and deleting `.git/lfs` still leaves the LFS placeholder objects in the repo itself.